# Gzip Compression - Not Videos

Tags: html, video, compression, gzip, mp4

A site I'm working on uses HTML5 for videos, and I've noticed that on iOS devices, the videos don't work if I have Gzip enabled. Obviously I don't want to disable Gzip entirely, but is it possible filter out video files from compression?

Here is the code in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s,?\s(gzip|deflate)?|X{4,13}|~{4,13}|-{4,13})$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
<IfModule filter_module>
  FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))/
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)/
  FilterChain     COMPRESS
  FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_filter.c>
  # Legacy versions of Apache
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
</IfModule>

# Webfonts and SVG:
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff)$" >
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: did you try `mod_gzip_item_exclude mime video/.*` ?

Comment: That seems to have worked, cheers!

Comment: can u post your final code which would be useful for others